# Mocha/Chai: Test for exact throw error result

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, chai

There is a simple method, which throws an error:

**methods.js**

```
insertItem = new ValidatedMethod({
    name    : 'article.insert.item',
    validate: new SimpleSchema({
        parent: { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id }
        value : { type: String }
    }).validator(),

    run({ parent, value}) {
        var isDisabled = true
        if (isDisabled)
            throw new Meteor.Error('example-error', 'There is no reason for this error :-)')
    }
})
```

Now I want to do a **mocha** test for this error. So I came up with this, which is working:

**server.test.js**

```
it('should not add item, if element is disabled', (done) => {
    const value = 'just a string'

    function expectedError() {
        insertItem.call(
            {
                parent: '12345',
                value
            }
        )
    }

    expect(expectedError).to.throw
    done()
})
```

Until this point everything is working.

**The problem**

But I would like to test for the exact error message.

I already tried

```
expect(expectedError).to.throw(new Meteor.Error('example-error', 'There is no reason for this error :-)'))
```

But it gives me a failing test:

```
Error: expected [Function: expectedError] to throw 'Error: There is no reason for this error :-) [example-error]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966821/testing-for-errors-thrown-in-mocha) that I needed to write it like this:

```
expect(expectedError).to.throw(Meteor.Error(), 'example-error', 'This is an error');
```

Note that the error messages are after the Error(),

Comment: I'm finding that the second string seems not to be checked, so it is probably better to write expect(expectedError).to.throw(Meteor.Error(), 'example-error');

Answer (score 0):

I think the docs are a bit misleading/confusing on this - just remove the `new` operator from your `expect` and it'll match the error thrown:

`expect(expectedError).to.throw(Meteor.Error('example-error', 'There is no reason for this error :-)'))`

Comment: Also, you've got `var disabled = true` BUT `if (isDisabled)` in the next line - but I'm assuming this is just example code not copied from your function

Comment: With this the test is still failing: `Error: expected [Function: expectedError] to throw an error`

Comment: @user3142695 I've tested the above a couple of times with your example code and it throws the correct error. Have you both removed the  `new` and changed the `var disabled` / `if(isDisabled)` parts?